# Pygame Collision Error

Tags: python, pygame, collision, rect

I am coding a simple dodging kinda game in pygame, hopefully I will develop it to build something like Asteroids.

I have used `.collidelist()` to recognize collision with my randomly generated "asteroids". But when the player goes under or above the asteroid, a collision is detected.

```
# -------------------- COLLISION  --------------------
        collision =  player_rect.collidelist(objects)
        if collision != -1:
            lives -= 1
            if lives >= 0:
                gameLoop()
            else:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
```

My asteroids only seem to be moving in the vertical direction, not horizontal even though I have changed their horizontal value.

```
for x in random_x_pos:
            random_y_pos[random_x_pos.index(x)] += object_y_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]
            x += object_x_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodge')

#icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
#pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# -------------------- Colours  --------------------
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
pink = (233,30,98)

# -------------------- Variables  --------------------
display_width = 600
display_height = 600
FPS = 60
lives = 3

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

# -------------------- Actual Game  --------------------
def gameLoop():
    global lives
    # -------------------- Player  --------------------
    player_dim = 20
    x_pos = ((display_width / 2) - player_dim)
    y_pos = ((display_height / 2) - player_dim)
    vel = 5
    player_rect = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, pink, (x_pos, y_pos, player_dim, player_dim))

    # -------------------- Random Objects  --------------------
    object_dimensions  = 30
    amount_of_objects = 10
    random_x_pos, random_y_pos, object_x_vel, object_y_vel, objects = [], [], [], [], []
    for int in range(amount_of_objects):
        x, y, x_vel, y_vel = random.randint(0, display_width), random.randint(0, display_height), random.randint(-5,5), random.randint(-5,5)
        rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (x, y, 30, 30))
        again = rect1.colliderect(player_rect)
        while again:
            x, y = random.randint(0, display_width), random.randint(0, display_height)
            rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (x, y, 30, 30))
            again = rect1.colliderect(player_rect)
        random_x_pos.append(x)
        random_y_pos.append(y)
        object_x_vel.append(x_vel)
        object_y_vel.append(y_vel)

    # -------------------- Event Handling  --------------------
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y_pos > 0:
            y_pos -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and (y_pos + player_dim) < display_height:
            y_pos += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_pos > 0:
            x_pos -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and (x_pos + player_dim) < display_width:
            x_pos += vel

        for x in random_x_pos:
            random_y_pos[random_x_pos.index(x)] += object_y_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]
            x += object_x_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]

        # -------------------- COLLISION  --------------------
        collision =  player_rect.collidelist(objects)
        if collision != -1:
            lives -= 1
            if lives >= 0:
                gameLoop()
            else:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        player_rect = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, pink, (x_pos, y_pos, player_dim, player_dim))
        for obj in random_x_pos:
            y = random_y_pos[random_x_pos.index(obj)]
            var = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (obj, y, object_dimensions, object_dimensions))
            objects.append(var)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `for obj in random_x_pos:` loop, you're appending new rects to the `objects` lists like crazy. You don't move and draw these old rects, so you get thousands of invisible rects pretty quickly which are still used for the collision detection.

You have to restructure the code. I suggest to create a list of rects together with their velocities.

```
objects = []

for i in range(amount_of_objects):
    rect = pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, display_width), random.randint(0, display_height), 30, 30)
    velocity = [random.randint(-5,5), random.randint(-5,5)]
    # Put the rect and the velocity into a list and append it to the objects.
    objects.append([rect, velocity])
```

Update the rect positions in a for loop. You can do the collision detection at the same time.

```
collision = False
for rect, velocity in objects:
    rect.x += velocity[0]
    rect.y += velocity[1]

    if player_rect.colliderect(rect):
        collision = True

if collision:
    lives -= 1
    # etc.
```

Draw the rects like so:

```
for rect, velocity in objects:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, rect)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

One of your problems lies in this code fragment:

```
for x in random_x_pos:
            random_y_pos[random_x_pos.index(x)] += object_y_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]
            x += object_x_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]
```

In this loop, `x` is the loop variable which changes in every cycle of the loop. The line `x += object_x_vel[random_x_pos.index(x)]` has no effect on the code because this is immediately followed by the next loop iteration in which x is assigned to the next value of `random_x_pos`.

Instead, you could try something like this:

```
for i in range(len(random_x_pos)):
            random_y_pos[i] += object_y_vel[i]
            random_x_pos[i] += object_x_vel[i]
```

Notice, however, that there are other flaws in your code. For example, you assign the python internal `int` to a loop variable and hence override it. This can lead to unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much.